# Awk with Printf usage

Tags: shell, awk, printf

i am trying to use `awk` to filter the output of a `autorep` command

output of `autorep` command:

```
/tmp $ autorep -j Test_Job -q


/* ----------------- Test_Job ----------------- */

insert_job: Test_Job job_type: CMD
box_name: Test_box
command: echo
machine: machine_name
owner: ownername
permission: gx,ge,wx
date_conditions: 0
condition: s(testjob1)
description: "echo"
std_out_file: "/tmp/test_job.out"
std_err_file: "/tmp/test_job.err"
alarm_if_fail: 1
alarm_if_terminated: 1


/tmp $ autorep -j Test_Job2 -q

/* ----------------- Test_Job2 ----------------- */

insert_job: Test_Job2   job_type: CMD
command: echo
machine: machinename
owner: owner
permission:
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr
start_mins: 9,19,29,39,49,59
run_window: "06:00-19:00"
description: "test discription"
std_out_file: "/tmp/Test_Job2.out"
std_err_file: "/tmp/Test_Job2.err"
alarm_if_fail: 1
alarm_if_terminated: 1
```

i have the below shell script to filter out the data:

```
 #!/bin/bash
  
      TXT=/tmp/test1.txt
      CSV=/tmp/test1.csv
  
       echo "Enter the JOB_NAME or %SEARCHSTRING%"
  
       while read -r i;
          do
   awk '$1 == "insert_job:" {printf "%s %s ", $2, $4}; $1 == "condition:" {printf "%s ", $2}; $1 == "days_of_week:" {printf "%s ", $2}; $1 == "date_conditions:" {printf "%s\n ", $2}' < <(autorep -j $i -q) >$TXT
   echo
     break
      done
 
     if [ -s $TXT ]
       then
          (echo "job_name,job_type,Date_Conditions,Days_of_week/Conditions"; cat test1.txt) |  sed 's/ \+/,/g' > $CSV
       else
          echo "Please check the %SEARCHSTRING% or JOB_NAME"
     fi
```

the output I am looking for:

```
Test_Job CMD 0 s(testjob1)
Test_Job2 CMD 1 mo,tu,we,th,fr 9,19,29,39,49,59 "06:00-19:00"
```

but the command is not working and i am getting the data like below:

```
Test_Job CMD 00s(testjob1) Test_Job2 CMD 1 mo,tu,we,th,fr 9,19,29,39,49,59 "06:00-19:00"
```

can someone help me out with getting the correct output

EDIT:

Let me explain what i am trying to do. i am using the below command and i am giving a key word as `%Test%` (which will fetch all the jobs with name Test in it), so i will be basically running this query on all the jobs with that keyword and inturn would be getting a list with the filtered out options as per my query. i am getting the getting the data but all the data is on one line rather that each job data on each line:

EDIT 2:

So as you can see if `date_condition: 0` then the job may or may not have `condition:` in it and if a job has `date_condition: 1` then it will have 'days_of_week:' and may or may not have other fields like 'run_window:'.

so is there a way i can modify the script to print out maybe 'N/A' if some field is missing. And also if i get the data on each line individually

Comment: `/condition/` also matches `date_conditions`. And you need a space in `/date_conditions/ {printf "%s ", $2}`. Try `awk '$1 == "insert_job:" {printf "%s %s ", $2, $4}; $1 == "date_conditions:" {printf "%s ", $2}; $1 == "condition:" {printf "%s", $2}' `.

Comment: I would write it as `/^condition/`, not `/condition/`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say this in your question, but I'm assuming there are multiple jobs output by `autorep`. You need to keep track of the transition from one job to another in the output. You also need to anchor your regexes to prevent false matches.

```
awk '/^insert_job/ {if (flag) {printf "\n"}; printf "%s %s ", $2, $4; flag = 1}; /^date_conditions/ {printf "%s", $2}; /^condition/ {printf "%s", $2}' < <(autorep -j Test_Job -q)
```

This outputs a newline before each "insert_job" (and thus each job) after the first so each line of output is a different job.

Multiple lines for readability:

```
awk '
    /^insert_job/ {if (flag) {printf "\n"}; 
                   printf "%s %s ", $2, $4; 
                   flag = 1}; 
    /^date_conditions/ {printf "%s", $2}; 
    /^condition/ {printf "%s", $2}
' < <(autorep -j Test_Job -q)
```

Comment: Sorry for not explaining my question correctly, i have updated it now and have mentioned what exactly i am trying to do. i am also trying to get the data coming from the '''awk''' command into a csv file.

Comment: @NecroCoder: The principle I illustrate using the `flag` remains the same.

Comment: i am very new to shell scripting, would you mind explaining how can i use flag in my scenario?

Comment: `awk '
    /insert_job/ {printf "%s %s ", $2, $4};
    /date_conditions/ {printf "%s ", $2};
    /^condition|days_of_week|run_calendar|start_times|start_mins/ {if (flag);
                   printf "%s ", $2;
                   flag = 1};
                   {if (flag);
                   printf "NA ";
                   flag = 0};
  /alarm_if_fail/ {if (flag) {printf "\n"};
                   flag = 1}
' < <(autorep -j autosys_dpmd1_maintr1136_cleanfiles -q)`

Comment: Above is what i was able to conjure with your code but i am not getting the correct results.

Comment: @NecroCoder: `flag` in my answer is only intended to control whether a newline is printed. The newline is printed before each beginning of record (lines where "insert_job" appears). The only reason `flag` is there is to prevent printing a newline before the first record. You could omit any reference to `flag` and my answer should still work because the key to the technique is simply the printing of the newline when an input line matches "insert_job".

Comment: your code works fine but also i would like this script to print `NA` if a string does not exist.

Comment: @NecroCoder: You've gone beyond the scope of the original question. You need to create a new question covering that requirement. In the mean time, Google the phrase "state machine in awk" and read some of the links in the result.